# Azure Reserved websites to virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to connect azure websites (type reserved mode) to a VM in an existing virtual network? I want to configure the connectionstring of the websites to the internal ip of the SQL Server VM and not over it's public ip due to security reasons.

I know that it works with a web/workerrole to connect directly to the internal ip, but it's no option to create all websites within a webrole....

Answer (score 0):

No we don't support Virtual Network (yet) but you can consider using Service Bus Relay for some scenarios, look at http://www.bradygaster.com/windowsazurewebsites-onprem-servicebus